# Flutter Build Fail after reinstalling Windows

Tags: java, windows, flutter, dart, build

I reinstalled Windows and AndroidStudio, now my project gets this Build error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:signingConfigWriterDebug'.
> java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: E:<theprojectpath>\build\app\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I fixed it:

1. Delete your build-cache and your cache folder in your .android folder.
   Usually located here C:\Users\username\.android
2. Delete the build folder in your flutter project folder.
   (...)\flutter_project_name\build